# Let $G$ be a group such that $|G|=pqr$, where p,q,r are not neccesarily distinct primes. Show $G$ is soluable.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Let $G$ be a group such that $|G|=pqr$, where p,q,r are not neccesarily distinct primes. Show $G$ is soluable.

$Proof$: Since $G$ is a p-group, $Z(G) \neq 1$. We can exploit this fact to show that the upper central series of $G$ expires and thus $G$ is nilpotent. Since $G$ is nilpotent, it is soluable.

Will this route of reasoning work?

Comment: In general, $G$ is not a $p$-group (unless $p=q=r$).

Comment: Ah, right... So I guess I did case #1.. Hmm..

Case #2: $|G|=p^2r$ with $r < p$. It follows that $n_p=1$ and $[G:P]=r$ so is abelian, and also $P$ is abelian, so we have found an abelian series.

Case #3: if we now do the previous case for $p < r$ then we do not get a normal subgroup $R$ unless $r$ does not divide $p^2-1$. Hm... Trying to figure out how to continue this case... I don't think I can use the existense of a subgroup $H$ s.t. $[G:H]=p$ (the smallest prime dividing g) since the multiplicity on prime factor p is 2.